# Python check all file with a specific name in a directory

Tags: python, list, file, glob

I have a file name (`mytest.`) with 3 or more suffix ("*.txt","*.shp","*.shx","*.dbf") in a directory (`path = 'C://sample'`). I wish to list all files with the same name

I know with `import glob` is possible to list all file with a specific suffix

My question is how to list all "mytest" in the directory

```
ex 

mytest.txt
mytest.shp
mytest.bdf
mytest.shx

mylist = ["mytest.txt","mytest.shp","mytest.bdf","mytest.shx"]


mytest.txt
mytest.shp
mytest.bdf
mytest.shx
mytest.pjr

mylist = ["mytest.txt","mytest.shp","mytest.bdf","mytest.shx","mytest.pjr"]
```

Comment: Then, what's your question?

Comment: Thanks Maxime. My question is how to list all "mytest" in the directory

Comment: There is no dictionary here, so...what's your question?

Comment: `glob.glob('mytest.*')` will do the job.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're looking for the [`glob` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html), as you said in your question, but with the wildcard on the extension:

```
import glob
glob.glob("mytest.*")
```

Example:

```
$ ls
a.doc  a.pdf  a.txt  b.doc

$ python
Python 2.7.3 (default, Dec 18 2012, 13:50:09) [...]
>>> import glob
>>> glob.glob("a.*")
['a.doc', 'a.pdf', 'a.txt']
>>>
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have other files named `mylist` that don't have the extensions you're looking for, this may be a better solution:

```
import glob

extensions = ["txt","shp","bdf","shx"] # etc

mylist = list()
for ext in extensions:
    mylist += glob.glob("mylist.{}".format(ext))
```

Or probably even easier:

```
mylist = [item for item in glob.glob('mylist.*') if item[-3:] in extensions]
```